# Is there a way to schedule exact alarms with an AlarmManager on device reboot WITHOUT the user running the app in Android 8+?

Tags: android, push-notification, calendar, alarmmanager, boot

After a reboot, calendar apps somehow restore all the alarms without the user having to run the app at any time. I am trying to do the same for a medication reminder app, but the receivers only work after I run the app manually after a reboot.

Here's my code:

**(Part of) AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

...

```
    <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".StartupService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
```

**BootReceiver**

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction() == null) {
            StartupService.enqueueWork(context);
        }
        else {
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel("memo_channel", "My Memo", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX);
                notificationChannel.setDescription("Memo Notification Channel");
                notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
                notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
                notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
                notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
            }
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "memo_channel");
            notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setShowWhen(true)
                    .setTicker("Reminder")
                    .setContentTitle("Memo")
                    .setContentText("This is a sample notification.")
                    .setContentInfo("Information")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.head);

            notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
        }
    }
}
```

**StartupService:**

```
public class StartupService extends JobIntentService {
    private static final int UNIQUE_JOB_ID=1337;

    static void enqueueWork(Context ctxt) {
        enqueueWork(ctxt, StartupService.class, UNIQUE_JOB_ID,
                new Intent(ctxt, StartupService.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void onHandleWork(Intent i) {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "I ran!");
    }
}
```

**TECHNICAL SPECIFICATIONS**

**Compile SDK version:** 29

**Min SDK version:** 24

**Testing device:** HUAWEI P40 Pro ELS-NX9 (**Android 10**; EMUI 11.0.0.0)

Answer (score 1):

For now, there is not a single solution for all devices. Most of the phone manufacturers prevent some apps launches to save power. In Huawei devices, users can manually allow the app to launch on startup or in the background. And, this can not be programmatically enabled. As a developer, you can prompt your users to perform the steps manually. Additionally, these settings can be shown to users programmatically.

Check the device is Huawei;

```
private boolean isDeviceHuawei() {
    if (Build.BRAND == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return Build.BRAND.toLowerCase().equals("huawei");
    }
}
```

Show to users App launch settings;

```
private void showHuaweiLaunchSettings() {
    try {
        showActivity("com.huawei.systemmanager",
                "com.huawei.systemmanager.startupmgr.ui.StartupNormalAppListActivity");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        showActivity("com.huawei.systemmanager",
                "com.huawei.systemmanager.optimize.bootstart.BootStartActivity");
    }
}
```

For intent;

```
private void showActivity(String packageName, String activityDir) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, activityDir));
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

With minor changes, you can also apply this solution to other devices.

Comment: I'll try it in the next days and I'll keep you updated. Thank you!